# SQLAlchemy: is it possible to store session wide properties

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I am working on a software that manipulates SQL tables using SQLALchemy.
Each operation a user will perform (insertion, modification, deletion) must be logged on a specific LOG table.

The log table looks like this:

```
    +-----------+----------------------------------------------+
    |  user_id  |  log                                         |
    +-----------+----------------------------------------------+
    |       21  |  Value x added in table y                    |
    |       12  |  Value z deleted from table w                |
```

To write such logs, I have a function define in the table Log that insert a new log with the following prototype.

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String)

        @staticmethod
    def insert(value):
        item = Foo()
        item.value = value
        session.add(item)
        Log.add(item)


class Log(Base):
    user_id = Column(Integer, not_null=True)
    value = Column(String, not_null=True)

    @saticmethod
    def add(item):
        logitem = Log()
        logitem.user_id = x
        logitem.value = "Insertion of %s" % item.value
        session.add(logitem)
```

The code above does not work because 'x' for user is not defined.

I don't want to pass the user_id as an argument when I call the Foo.insert method. I would like to know if it is possible to bind the user_id to the session so that the user_id would be define once and persist for all sql queries.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions have an [info](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.info) attribute, a user-modifiable dictionary. The dictionary can be pre-populated when a session is created, and modified and accessed thereafter:

```py
s = Session(info={'foo': 'bar'})
foo = s.info['foo']
s.info['baz'] = 'quux'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't use the session as a global namespace, and it doesn't look like a good idea anyway. If you really need to do that, it should be done by your application, using any other global or session state you have, not by coupling SQLAlchemy to your authentication/user-session process.

Comment: One use case for this is to add a hook on foreignkey append event.

Say Foo has a OneToMany relationship to Bar defined by
    mapper("Foo",foo_table,property{'bar'=relationship(Bar)})

Then I can access to all child bar item, from Foo, using foo.bar
I can also add a bar item to foo, using

    foo.bar.append(new_bar)

I can add an event listener to log such insertions, however the listener needs to be able to retrieve the user login.

Comment: Fine, but there's no reason for that to not be in the application context. There's no need to create a session namespace for that.

Comment: Well I could modify my hook to call a method from my application, but then the model will be entangled to the application. On the other hand if my information is in the session, then It could simply be missing and the hook can use a default username.